# Weird rectangle font in Volume Mixer

Tags: windows, fonts

Problem mentioned in the title: Weird rectangle font in Volume Mixer

How can solve this problem?

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: That should be a down icon. Have you been messing with your system fonts?

Comment: This sometimes happens on clean installs too, which is weird. The solution is to restore known-good font files.